# How I can transfer matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, transform, transfer

```
#Example:
A = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[3,2,1,4],[2,1,4,3]]
#How I can transform matrix A become matrix B 
#with matrix B I want to become...
B = [[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4],
     [4],
     [3],
     [2],
     [1],
     [3],
     [2],
     [1],
     [4],
     [2],
     [1],
     [4],
     [3]]
```

And when I save .txt or .csv how I can transfer data without [] in all of the data?

Comment: `[[x] for xs in A for x in xs]` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: **without []** means you want output like this `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, but you can help me exactly code in this case? because it's still not working.

Comment: are  you willing to use an appropriate format like JSON instead of txt or csv ?

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, I want that after the data transfer.

Comment: @azro I don't have experiment with JSON, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write full**

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[3,2,1,4],[2,1,4,3]]
B = []

for Am in A:
  for x in Am:
    B.append([x])

print (B)
```

**Write short**

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[3,2,1,4],[2,1,4,3]]
B = [[x] for Am in A for x in Am]
print (B)
```

[Link Example](https://replit.com/@Vuong_Huu_Thien/How-I-can-transfer-matrix-in-Python#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

using chain

```
from itertools import  chain
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3]]
data = [[x] for xs in lst for x in xs]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(data))
print(data)
print(result)

>>> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [4], [3], [2], [1], [3], [2], [1], [4], [2], [1], [4], [3]]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Comment: How I can save data by one column?

Comment: it is already given in above comment by @falsetru. i just edited it